# how connect app made with android studio with dbconnect.php and login.php in local

Tags: php, android

I have two files.php in local:

dbconnect.php:

```
 <?php
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','root');
    define('PASS','');
    define('DB','androiddb');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
```

and login.php:

```
<?php 

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        //Getting values 
        $username = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //Creating sql query
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$username' AND password='$password'";

        //importing dbConnect.php script 
        require_once('dbConnect.php');

        //executing query
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        //fetching result
        $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        //if we got some result 
        if(isset($check)){
            //displaying success 
            echo "success";
        }else{
            //displaying failure
            echo "failure";
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
    }
```

Now, how can I `connect` my app with these `two files`??

Thanks in advance everybody!

Also, what I must write in config.java?

`public static final String LOGIN_URL =""`?

Comment: In local? What do you mean?

Comment: i need test app before in local, i need to register user and login user in local before

Comment: What is local? Please answer.

Comment: i need to create record in db with name and password but when i click on "go" i have this message:"#1036 table is read only"...why?

Comment: You are not going to tell what you mean by in local?